# How can I enforce that a function returns both of the stated union type?

Tags: typescript

I have created a response object and a subsequent utility type that turns the values into a union. I want my controller to return all types within the union. However, TypeScript will consider a function valid if it only returns one of the types. How can I make it valid only if it returns all types?

```js
// mocking Zod, I'll use custom for everything in example
const z = {
    custom: function <T>() {
        return undefined as unknown as T
    },
}

type TestResponseType = {
    200: unknown,
    [status: number]: unknown
}

const response = {
    200: z.custom<object>(),
    404: z.custom<number>()
} satisfies TestResponseType

type TransformRoutes<T extends TestResponseType> = () => Promise<
    {[P in keyof T]: T[P]}[keyof T]
>

// How can I make TypeScript check that this function is returning a number and an object in different routes?
const shouldBeInvalid: TransformRoutes<typeof response> = async () => {
    return 1;
}

const valid: TransformRoutes<typeof response> = async () => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) return {};
    else return 1;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-OacDGxLXXO62PmhTDwFgsPhURBbPEEigAfmU9Q0FCEeKImAAQlQ8IhuFIiPBMJZnOjMRwcUnCSiqMKPZS9rS9PF+DZ6d4dLTWiZPcFQgBGADca3Tm1AJbLFbRGPBtdx+IbTWb2121HbcQoXegPcZBxM0fpAFkxkITtXMEwGbSOicAKzeIchAw5Cd+KhEagtr2jhOORAA)

Comment: Please put your code as plaintext in the question itself.

Comment: TS won't do this for you automatically.  I assume you know that `()=>number` is intentionally assignable to `() => number | object`, and that you're asking for this not because you think the current behavior is unsafe, but because you want a linter-like feature to warn you about returns that happen not to exhaust the expected type. Well you can write code which will have an error somewhere if that's true, but it's not going to be a simple syntax... like maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NaEy6N) meets your needs? Let me know if you want to see that written up as an answer.

Comment: That could work, but you're right, it's not a simple syntax. Thank you for your help regardless! I'll mark that as the answer.

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance.  I'm going to put your code as plaintext in your question as asked; hopefully that's okay with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript won't enforce such a restriction for you, especially for function returns; one of the basic features of the type system is that if a type `A` is assignable to a type `B`, then you should be allowed to return a value of type `A` whenever a value of type `B` is expected.  And any type `A` is assignable to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `A` with something else.  So `number` is assignable to `number | object`.  Indeed this is intentionally supported so that the contract of a function as described by the call signature can be separated from the details of the function implementation.  You wouldn't want this to fail:

```
function foo(): string {
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? "hello" : "goodbye";
}
```

with the error that the return type `string` should actually be `"hello" | "goodbye"` and that it's *invalid* to allow for the possibility of other strings.
The issue you're having isn't really one of *validity*, but rather more of a linter error to make sure that you haven't accidentally left out some possibility.

---

It's possible you could write a custom [typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io/) rule to do this for you.  Barring that, there are ways to write code that will give an error in your situation, but it's only by rephrasing what you're doing to a form that really is invalid.  Here's one possibility:

```
const mutuallyAssignable =
    <T extends U, U extends V, V = T>(t: T, dummyU: U) => t;
```

Here the `mutuallyAssignable` function accepts two arguments: a `t` of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `T`, and a `dummyU` of generic type `U`, where each of `T` and `U` are [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be assignable to each other.  The function just returns `t` and ignores `dummyT` (hence the "dummy" name).  So if you're looking to ensure that your function is assignable both to *and from* the desired type, then you can pass your function in as `t` and any value of the desired type as `dummyU` (and because you're not using that value, you can even *pretend* to have such a value, such as using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)) and the compiler will check the two types more "exactly":

```
const shouldBeInvalid = mutuallyAssignable(async () => {
    return 1;
}, null! as TransformRoutes<typeof response>); // error!
// Type 'number | object' is not assignable to type 'number'.    

const valid = mutuallyAssignable(async () => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) return {};
    else return 1;
}, null! as TransformRoutes<typeof response>); // okay
```

That behaves how you want, but the syntax is ugly, mostly because you really have to work against the type system to get this behavior.  There are almost certainly alternative approaches, but I don't know if any of them would be more aesthetically appealing than this.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKAXIgzlAJxjAHNEBvAKERsQIFMoQCkBZAQygAsA6A9sABM4AW0yIAPIgAMPAKyIA-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-TQDhuD4ARhDEQdzVkORByvCYKBsawRk0HE1Jve9bECZ8NDfHZek-FUf01bVqOAhhpWxehwMsIA)